# Can't start MongoDB configuration server via docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to run a MongoDB sharded cluster - 2 configuration servers, 3 shards and a router.

I tried it with docker compose, but it gave me many (same) errors,
so after an investigation I narrowed it down to the following...

All the config servers and the shards fail to start (i.e. I can't configure them yet).

When I run the following (which is a config server for example) (on ubuntu 18.04-minimal with a very strong machine):

```
docker run -it --rm -v /home/mongo/cfg01:/data/db -v ${PWD}/scripts:/scripts -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass mongo:latest mongod --auth --port 27017 --configsvr --replSet configserver
```

I get the following error (same as in docker compose, but singular):

```
BadValue: Cannot start a configsvr as a standalone server. Please use the option --replset to start the node as a replica set.
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

And when I tried to run it with `--replset` as it said instead of `--replSet`, I got the following error:

```
Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--replset'
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

Comment: I would suggest to use a [configuration file](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/) instead of command line arguments. See also [Configuration File Settings and Command-Line Options Mapping](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-file-settings-command-line-options-mapping/)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I understand you, but what's wrong with what I'm doing ?

Comment: I don't know docker, so I don't know what and how Docker tries to start the mongod instances. Sorry.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit you can have a look at https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/a5085fbda43201055b88e92613bce6d05d18f77b/5.0/Dockerfile the `RUN` commands are simply sh commands that run on build of the original container